# Laravel website blink and load half page than full page

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel

**EDIT**

Problem solved by Shailendra

But if you see box no. 9-10-11 in screenshot something grayish thing load before full website, what is that?

[image]

I am working on a laravel project (test website)

```
https://whoisdatabox.com/
```

The webpage load 1st a page without CSS and then load full

Before that, I was working on (live website)

`https://whoisdatacenter.com/` (it load fine to me)

Is that like my website cached only .blade.PHP files and not CSS, or I am doing some else mistake?

i.e. I am not getting in which file I made a mistake

I check files I update in the test website in the last 48 hours by

```
find . -mtime -2 -ls | grep -v "framework\|session"

3526181    4 -rw-r--r--   1 whoisbox whoisbox      901 Apr  8 14:28 ./.env

15276161    4 drwxr-xr-x   3 whoisbox whoisbox     4096 Apr  8 15:07 ./resources/views

15276062   44 -rw-r--r--   1 whoisbox whoisbox    44090 Apr  7 20:01 ./resources/views/home.blade.php

15276025    8 -rw-r--r--   1 whoisbox whoisbox     4668 Apr  7 20:01 ./resources/views/free.blade.php

15276183    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 whoisbox whoisbox     4096 Apr  8 16:49 ./resources/views/layout

15276096    4 -rw-r--r--   1 whoisbox whoisbox      490 Apr  8 16:49 ./resources/views/layout/default.blade.php

15276095    4 -rw-r--r--   1 whoisbox whoisbox     1549 Apr  8 16:49 ./resources/views/layout/head.blade.php

15276042    4 -rw-r--r--   1 whoisbox whoisbox     3752 Apr  7 20:01 ./resources/views/layout/nav-main.blade.php

15276044    4 -rw-r--r--   1 whoisbox whoisbox      133 Apr  7 20:01 ./resources/views/layout/footer-script.blade.php

15276186    4 -rw-r--r--   1 whoisbox whoisbox     2861 Apr  7 17:07 ./resources/views/layout/default.blade.php.zip

15276046    4 -rw-r--r--   1 whoisbox whoisbox     1084 Apr  7 20:01 ./resources/views/layout/footer.blade.php

15276008    4 -rw-r--r--   1 whoisbox whoisbox      733 Apr  7 23:56 ./resources/views/layout/head.blade.php.zip

4308654    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 whoisbox whoisbox     4096 Apr  7 16:45 ./routes

4310368    8 -rw-r--r--   1 whoisbox whoisbox     4726 Apr  7 16:45 ./routes/web.php

7442463    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 whoisbox whoisbox     4096 Apr  8 16:28 ./app/Http/Controllers

7442207   12 -rw-r--r--   1 whoisbox whoisbox     8990 Apr  8 16:23 ./app/Http/Controllers/sql.php

7442203   28 -rw-r--r--   1 whoisbox whoisbox    28500 Apr  8 16:28 ./app/Http/Controllers/TableController.php
```

I check on google page speed test . it show me same...

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwhoisdatabox.com%2F&tab=desktop

The score is 90% but the blink is there in screenshot as well...

[image]

Comment: put your external css files at the beginning of the file in head section and all javascript files at the end of file and make sure you load jquery first in your javascript libraries and then load rest of the javascript files

Comment: it seems like your css and javascript loads after your content loads

Comment: You might want to make sure you're delivering valid html, as it looks there's a `</head>` before `<!doctype>` and some `<meta>` elements and stylesheet links at the bottom of the page that belong in the `<head>`.